# are plaetze (squares) included in the google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places Api in order to show a list of nearby places to the user. I am trying to include in the list the plaetze (squares) like Paradeplatz in Zurich:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Paradeplatz,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Schweiz&hl=el&ie=UTF8&ll=47.36996,8.539225&spn=0.001817,0.004823&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=34.808514,79.013672&oq=paradeplatz&hq=Paradeplatz,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Schweiz&t=m&z=18

No matter if i include all the supported Places types from here:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

the Paradeplatz does not appear. Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paradeplatz](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?address=Paradeplatz,%20Zurich,%20Schweiz&q=Paradeplatz) does appear in the Places data.  Looks like it is in approximately the right place, not sure how to search for only "plaetze".

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems that plaetze are type of establishment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested specifically in displaying squares, perhaps try searching via `name` parameter with a value like `Platz` (`square`) instead of using the `types` parameter. Searching by category (`types` parameter) might return fewer (or none) results than expected if Google hasn't yet added the actual categories to the items in its Places API database.